# How to implement HTTPS support for Flask HTTP server running as Kubernetes container

Tags: python, https, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

A Python based `Flask` HTTP server is running on Google Kubernetes cluster as `Docker` container. It is implemented as a single pod `flask-http-deployment` and placed behind a `Load Balancer`.

The HTTP server's Python code is quite simple and does not support `HTTPS` protocol. But other applications will need to communicate with this server via HTTPS. So there is a need to implement a support for `HTTPS`.

From what I read (please correct me if I am wrong), the `HTTPS` support could be implemented by configuring the `flask-http-deployment` with a `secret`.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Generated the `my-cert.crt` and `my-key.key` files:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout my-key.key -out my-cert.crt -subj '//CN=mydomain.com'`

2. With `my-cert.crt` and `my-key.key` files in place I created Kubernetes `secret`:

`kubectl create secret tls my-secret --key=my-key.key --cert=y-cert.crt`

How should I now modify the `flask-http-deployment` yaml file with a `secret` I've just created?

```
      apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
      kind: Deployment
      metadata:
        name: flask-http-deployment
      spec:
        replicas: 5
        minReadySeconds: 10
        strategy:
          type: RollingUpdate
          rollingUpdate:
            maxUnavailable: 1
            maxSurge: 1
        template:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: flask-http-app
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: flask-http-container
              image: gcr.io/my-project-id/flask-http-container
              ports:
              - containerPort: 80
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Here is the Load Balancer yaml, in case it is needed:

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: flask-http-load-balancer
    labels:
      app: flask-http-app
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30000
      protocol: TCP
      name: flask 
    selector:
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the secret , and where are you using the secret that you created , but supporting https is the same as in traditional world , put an https termination proxy in front of your app service , such as an nginx pod or an nginx ingress controller ( use your secret in there )

or terminate SSL/TLS in your external load balancer.

Comment: Would you please clarify how to configure the load balancer so it terminates SSL/TLS.

Comment: please see the documentation for nginx , nginx ingress

Answer (score 0):

Check out nginx ingress allows you to attach SSL certificates to your pods.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy