# Implement HTTPS support for a Flask API server running in Azure Kubernetes Service in a python container in Linux

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, flask, azure-aks

I am running a Flask API server in Python in a Linux Docker container on the Azure Kubernetes Service.
Right now, they communicate over HTTP, how would I go about letting them communicate via HTTPS?

I found the following thread, but am looking for some more information. Perhaps specific to Azure.
[How to implement HTTPS support for Flask HTTP server running as Kubernetes container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924890/how-to-implement-https-support-for-flask-http-server-running-as-kubernetes-conta)

My Deployment en Service look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: <image>
        env:
        - name: <token-secret-env-name>
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <token-secret-name>
              key: <token-secret>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "800Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "800Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: <port>

      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: <secret>
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-app
  ports:
  - port: <port>
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: <port>
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 0):

> how would I go about letting them communicate via HTTPS

I have tried as per the requirement running through HTTPS server.

- Used SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority (CA) for testing purpose.

Below is my deployment service files for both docker and Kubernetes.

**flask-app-deployment.yaml :**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydockerfile
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydockerfile
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mydockerfile
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mydockerfile
          image: *****.azurecr.io/mydockerfile
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssl-certificate
              mountPath: "/etc/ssl/certs"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: ssl-certificate
          secret:
            secretName: my-ssl-certificate
```

***sample.yaml :***

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydockerfile
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydockerfile
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mydockerfile
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mydockerfile
          image: ******.azurecr.io/mydockerfile:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: ssl-certificate
              mountPath: "/etc/ssl/certs"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: ssl-certificate
          secret:
            secretName: my-ssl-certificate
```

- Imaged the docker file to container.
  [image]
- Pushed the Docker image to the container registry
  [image]
- Logged into **Azure Container registry**
  [image]
- Applied the Kubernetes manifests to deploy the Flask API server.
  [image]
- Verified that the deployment is succeed.
  [image]

**Docker Images :**
[image]

Finally, It was communicating via HTTPS.

[image]